# Ideals generated by polynomials of the form $X_iY_j$ and $X_iY_j-Y_iX_j$ are radical?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Given $n \ge 1$ a integer and $C_1,C_2 \subset \{1,\dots,n\} \times \{1,\dots,n\}$ disjoint subsets, construct 
$$I(C_1,C_2) \subset k[X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_n]$$
the ideal generated by the set of polynomials
$$\{X_iY_j | (i,j) \in C_1\} \cup \{X_iY_j-Y_iX_j | (i,j) \in C_2\}.$$
Is $I(C_1,C_2)$ a radical ideal? If not, in which conditions does it fail to be?

I came across this kind of ideal during my PhD thesis study, so I have no idea about the veracity of the affirmation.

Comment: I think localizing at $X_i$ for all $i$ might work (recall that being radical is a local property). In the localization, the ideal is generated by $Y_iX_j$, which is radial (localize in all the $Y_i$).

Comment: Good idea, but I think this doesn't work because not all localization in prime ideals creates the inverse of $X_j.$ You can use this and induction to reduce to the case after the localization in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_n).$